# What kind of tool do I need to change my bottom bracket?

Tags: maintenance, bottom-bracket, tools

I want to replace my bottom bracket, but I have no idea what kind of tool to use.

[image]

What kind of bottom bracket is this? What tool do I need to change it?

Comment: What kinda bike is this ? This is a left-side videw, with the FD visible on the other side, and NUVO is a kickstand, but the angles are unusual.   Is it a cargo bike ?

Comment: Note that the tools will likely cost as much as the BB itself, and you will use them once a decade, if ever again. In this case, paying your local bike shop may be a better option.

Answer (score 10):

You have a traditional cup and cone BB. You need a lockring wrench to undo the locknut, such as ParkTool HCW-5, but many other exist. Then you will need a bottom bracket wrench, such as HCW-4, to get the bottom bracket out.

[image]

[image]

Photos from the Parktool marketing materials.

There are tutorials available, such as https://www.restoration.bike/bike-maintenance/old-style-bottom-bracket/

Answer (score 4):

Many replacement bottom brackets are available to replace a traditional bottom bracket design.  These will require a different tool(s) to install them than the tools you will need to remove the traditional bottom bracket (listed in different answer).

The specific tool(s) needed will be dictated once you determine the replacement bottom bracket you will use - the required tool(s) match the specific bottom bracket used.

If you are just doing maintenance on your current bottom bracket and plan to reinstall it, then the tools listed in the other answer are all that you will need. The same would be true if you were able to procure a new traditional-style bottom bracket to replace the current one.